# How to structure model showcase

Tags: customization, pages

I need to make a website of models that contain the following components:

1. Model page - model info, editorials of that particular model
2. Editorial page - containing some editorial info, link back to model, photographer, magazine, etc.
3. Photographer page - editorials of particular photographer
4. Magazine page - editorials that were published in this particular magazine
   (and maybe a few more)

I can use posts to do all this, but it might require a lot of time to manually rewrite info every time something is updated.

(Example. First we add some models, magazines & photographers. Now, when we post an editorial we can pick which models are in this photo session, who shot it and where was it published. When we publish the editorial it will automatically be shown on the page of each one of the mentioned above.)

I'm looking for any ideas that will make this easier. In other words, how to structure the website using WP.